# Any way of using english keybinding sets on StarCraft 2's localized versions?

Tags: starcraft-2, keyboard

I'm currently playing StarCraft 2's single player campaign, just for enjoying it without any hassle, but it appears that the localized versions keyboard shortcuts differ from the beta and had been localized so it's a real mess for me to go multi-player.

Is there a table with the English keybindings or a config file with them and a way to import them to the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that i'm not the only one that bothered on this, hence the [1.1 patch notes](http://us.starcraft2.com/launcher/patch-notes.htm)

> The Standard (US) and Standard for
>   Lefties (US) hotkey configurations are
>   now available in all regions.

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't a direct answer to your question, I would hope that Blizzard designed the "Grid" layout to work in non-QWERTY layouts, and I find it to be a much more hassle-free keyboard map than any of the default ones ever have been.

The command HUD menus are organized in a 5x3 grid,

> |1|2|3|4|5|
>   |1|2|3|4|5|
>   |1|2|3|4|5|

Or, to translate it better into my keyboard layout;

> |q|w|e|r|t|
>   |a|s|d|f|g|
>   |z|x|c|v|b|

So the middle-most command is ALWAYS d. The build SCV/Drone/Zergling is ALWAYS q, the cancel button is ALWAYS b. Attack is (always?) t.

Grid is sane, and the easiest way to remember/use the menus (in my own opinion, of course), assuming it works in your keyboard layout.

I don't know what Blizzard did and didn't do this for our non-QWERTY friends. Check out the game options and give it a shot?